# Extract text from gimp xcf files

Tags: bash, lisp, text-extraction, xcf

I can't get out from lisp, to pass to bash, in the same script...

```
 #!/bin/bash
{
gimp -n -i -b - <<EOF
(let* ( (file's (cadr (file-glob "*.xcf" 1))) (filename "") (image 0) (number 0) (condition 0) (testo "") )
  (while (pair? file's) 
...
  (gimp-quit 0)
  )
EOF
}

echo $testo;
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `testo` in your gimp code will not be reflected in your shell's environment. To do that, you would need to print the value and capture the output.

The general way of doing that in shell is `var=$(command)` (this sets the value of `var` to the standard output from `command`).

Comment: Thank you :) sdvds